# Functions.php file doesn't read stylesheet in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating wordpress theme by myself, but my functions.php doesn't work properly. I think there are a lot posts of this question, but I can't find proper one.

How I should fix it ?

My Code:

```
<?php

// Register Custom Navigation Walker
require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Pagrindinis Menu', 'Harionew' ),
) );

function apdaila_scripts() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'blain-basic-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

  wp_enqueue_style( 'apdaila-bootstrap-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/css/bootstrap.min.css", array('apdaila-fonts','apdaila-layout') );

  wp_enqueue_style( 'apdaila-main-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/css/main.css", array('apdaila-fonts','apdaila-layout') );

  wp_enqueue_script('apdaila-collapse', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/collapse.js', array('jquery') );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'apdaila-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery') );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'apdaila-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js', array('jquery') );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_script','apdaila_scripts');
?>
```

Comment: You need to post what errors you are getting. Also try debugging the code by removing all the lines of code (except `<?php` and `?>`), then adding them back in one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an 's' in your hook wp_enqueue_scripts
that should be `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','apdaila_scripts');`

Comment: I can't believe this mistake, LOL. Thank you !

Comment: That happens to everybody :D

Answer (score 1):

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );`
You have used wrong hook. Use 'wp_enqueue_scripts'

Answer (score 1):

You have write wrong hook for add scripts.

Please replace this line

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_script','apdaila_scripts');
```

to this line

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','apdaila_scripts');
```